# C++ - Min value in queue

Tags: c++, struct, queue

I have queue from struct type

```
struct test {
   int numbers;
};

queue<test> q;
```

how to find min value from:

```
q.front().numbers;
```

For example if in numbers have 5,1,3 I need to found 1.

Comment: `q.front().numbers;` is just a number, so that's the min...

Comment: Why are you not doing a std::qsort on your queue, and then fetching the number off front()

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, you might consider using a `std::priority_queue` instead. If you need to inspect the contents of your queue and preserve the order, you'll have to use an iterable container like a `std::deque` or `std::list` instead.

Comment: @AdityaKumarPandey: probably because std::queue has no iterator interface and std::sort would be better than qsort anyways?

Comment: Pop an element, compare it to current minimum, push it back. Repeat `q.size()`-times?

Comment: @AdityaKumarPandey: if all you wanted was the minimum value of a collection and nothing else, iterating over the collection would be far more sensible that sorting it, as it would be O(N). No sorting algorithm can be faster than that, after all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you need a queue of integers the easiest solution is to use [`std::deque<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque). Then you could use [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) to find the minimum element in the queue:

```
std::deque<int> q{5, 1, 3};
std::deque<int>::iterator it = std::min_element(q.begin(), q.end());
std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```

By doing so, you do not need to use the `struct test`. This is especially true since it seems to just store an integer. If, on the other hand, `struct test` is more complex (having more fields) then you can use exactly the same approach but defining a compare function for `struct test` (see @fljx answer for an example of such a compare function).

If you can only use a `queue` you are restricted on the type of operations that you can do. Therefore, you would need to do something like:

```
std::queue<int> q;
/* fill queue ... */
int min_value = INT_MAX;
std::size_t size = q.size();
while (size-- > 0) {
    int x = q.front();
    q.pop();
    q.push(x);
    if (x < min_value)
        min_value = x;
}
```

Comment: OP's got a `queue`, not `deque`.

Comment: @jrok Well, a `queue` is just a wrapper for `deque` limiting the types of operations you can do on the queue. It also prevents accessing to methods such as `begin` and `end` necessary to use `min_element`. So that is why I state in my answer that the easiest thing to do is to directly use a `deque`.

Comment: Ok, but I need to use queue not deque, can show me example with queue?

Comment: @NikolaiCekov If you can only use a `queue`, then the only way I can think of, is to empty all the queue in a loop and keep track of the minimum element you find while emptying it. That is definitely not a good idea if you want to preserve the `queue` after finding the minimum element, though. You may also insert the popped elements again in the queue, but this is a costly operation compared to using a `deque`.

Comment: @NikolaiCekov As a reference, I updated my answer to show an example only using `queue`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of pages explaining it around the web.

You need to create an `operator <` telling how your structure is to be compared.

```
struct test {
   int numbers;

    bool operator < ( const test &t ) const
    { return this->numbers < t.numbers; }
};
```

(I haven't tested this code for any silly error, but the links bellow may help if you find any problem).

After then, use `#include <algorithm>` to have access to `min_element()`.

References:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/
http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html

Comment: Since the OP needs a `queue`, `min_element` will not work (`queue` does not have `begin` and `end` operations).